# Postcat not working in Perl but works on CLI

Tags: perl

My error within the Perl Script:

"MailID: D3B921090
postcat: fatal: open D3B921090: No such file or directory"

"Subject:"

This command on the CLI works perfect:
"root@mail:/var/spool/postfix/deferred# postcat D3B921090|egrep "^Subject"

"Subject: test"

When I put it in my Perl script something breaks. I can't see anything wrong here as it even displays the files MailID, but the error states that it does not exist?

```
                   my $num = 0;
                   opendir my $dh, '/var/spool/postfix/deferred/' or die "Can't open directory: $!\n";
                    while ( my $node = readdir($dh) )
                    {
                            next if $node =~ /^\./;
                            print "MailID: $node\n";
                            my $subject = `postcat $node|egrep "^Subject"`;#Line of error
                            print "Subject: $subject\n";
                            $num++;
                    }
                    print "\nTotal: $num\n\n";
```

Comment: If there's a difference between a command that succeeds and a command you build, the first think you should have done is check for differences between the two!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CLI you are in the directory /var/spool/postfix/deferred and use postcat with a file inside this directory. In the perl script you are probably not in this directory, but nevertheless use only the filename with postcat, without giving the full path (readdir gives the name without the path).

Try to use `/var/spool/postfix/deferred/$node` instead of `$node`.

And BTW, if somebody puts a file named `";rm -rf /"` into the directory you are screwed, because the resulting command will be `"postcat; rm -rf / | .... "` - not funny (command injection).

Comment: Nit: `;rm -rf /` is not a legal file name. `; chdir .. ; chdir .. ; chdir .. ; chdir .. ; chdir .. ; rm -rf .` is, though.

Comment: You can use String::ShellQuote's `shell_quote` to fix that problem.

Comment: Nit: it does need to be a file name, the semicolon closes the current statement (postcat) and starts a new one. Just try `postcat; rm -rf /` on the command line :)

Comment: Back at you: Just try to create `; rm -rf /`. I have no idea what you're saying. I think you completely missed the point. I was saying that `/` is not allowed in file names, so I proposed an equivalent file name that *is* legal (i.e. doesn't use NUL or `/`).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: You may want to be careful using *"nit"*. Outside America it means *idiot* or *fool*.

Comment: sorry. I did not know that.